# Export a variable from inside the docker container to host

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell

I have container which does some process through shell script and exits once finished. There is a variable created during that process. Since this container will exit once the process is finished, Can I make this variable visible to host once the process is finished and the container exits?

Comment: You could create inside docker a file with the content of this variable, and read the file from outside of docker.

Comment: If you print the variable with `printf %q  "$varname"`, it is printed with the necessarily escape characters so that it can be read back easier.

Comment: Shell variables are never visible to their calling process, in Docker or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can let your container return the value in sysout. If the value is the only thing in sysout, you can do something like this

```
$ export myvar=$(docker run --rm ubuntu echo "Value returned")
$ echo $myvar
Value returned
$
```

Or you can have the container create a shell script that sets the variable. Put the shell script in a bind mount location and then run the script on the host when the container exits.